# How to set up redirect on first web-access from wireless?

Tags: redirect, web, wifi

I've noticed a lot of open wireless access points will associate but won't forward your traffic until you attempt a web connection.  This attempt is redirected to a TOU page.  If I want to do something similar, what's the "best" way to set this up?  I assume low-end WAPs (like the ubiquitous Linksys WRT54G) can't support this directly, so I'd set the WAP as a router (rather than gateway) and then use some kind of software on a Linux box to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load [ddWRT](http://dd-wrt.com) or [OpenWRT](http://openwrt.org) firmware on it; they both have captive portal support (which is what you're looking for). The process isn't super easy, but there are plenty of directions on both websites.